# Display two Surface Views over each other?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, augmented-reality

Is there any way to set two surface views over each other so that, one of them to hold a CameraPreview and the other to hold OpenGL surface.

I have attempted this problem and my attempts are mentioned below in (code1 and code2)

**Code 1**
1- in this code, I open the camera with command mentioned in line 1
2- instantiated an object from the Render Class, and add this object to the 
   surfaceView using setContentView()

but in this case, tha camera opens for few seconds and disaappears, then , the OpenGl object appearas.

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    camera = android.hardware.Camera.open(); //line 1
    //gLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    //gLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new MyRender());
    //setContentView(gLSurfaceView);
}
```

**Code 2**
In this code, I instantiate both of the CameraSurface and the Render Class.
and I also created a FrameLayout in the XML file. Then 
the camerSurface object is added to setContentView and the Render object to the FrameLayout.
but this way, causes only the object added to the framelayout to be displayed.

```
cameraSurfacePreviewDemo = new CameraSurfacePreviewDemo(this);
    glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new MyRender());
    //setContentView(cameraSurfacePreviewDemo);
    //setContentView(glSurfaceView);
    //fl01.addView(glSurfaceView);
    //fl01.addView(cameraSurfacePreviewDemo);
```

===========================================================================================
Any provision with good tutorials for beginners in Android Camera and AndR "Augmented Reality" Or suggesting good books for both beginners in Android Camera and AndR "Augmented Reality will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found any workaround? I'm stuck on the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC it is impossible.   Surface Views can not overlap.  (There was longer explanation from Diane Hackeborn)

Comment: what is IIRC? and what is the title of that article or book from Diane Hackeborn?

Comment: If I Remember it Correctly - Diane is an google engineur and has good contact to community.   Just google  it.